# Extract tables and columns from SQL query using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a regex for this task, but I really can't grasp the understanding of regex apart from very simple cases :-( :

The problem: I have this ("SQL like") query:

```
SELECT tcmcs003.*, tccom130.nama, tccom705.dsca, tcmcs052.dsca, tccom100.nama
FROM tcmcs003, tccom130,tccom705,tcmcs052,tccom100
WHERE  tcmcs003.cadr REFERS TO tccom130
 AND tcmcs003.casi REFERS TO tccom705
 AND tcmcs003.cprj REFERS TO tcmcs052
 AND tcmcs003.bpid REFERS TO tccom100
ORDER BY tcmcs003._index1
```

I want to "extract" all the **table names** and **column names**, and after that I want to simply add my characters to them...
For example replace:

```
 SELECT tcmcs003.*, tccom130.nama
```

with:

```
 SELECT tcmcs003XXX.*, tccom130XXX.namaYYY
```

Up to now I have the "best" regex I have is this:

```
(?<gselect>SELECT\s+)*(?<tname>\w{5}\d{3})*(?<spaces>[\.\,\s])+(?<colname>\w{4})*
```

And **replacement** pattern:

```
${gselect}${tname}XXX${spaces}${colname}YYY
```

The output is really terrible :-(

```
SELECT tcmcs003.
 m130
.nama
 m705
.dsca
 s052
.dsca
 m100
.nama

FROM
 s003
 m130
,m705
,s052
,m100

WHER
 s003
.cadr
 REFE

 m130

 s003
```

How can I write the regex?
I want to capture repeteately something like

```
[(any string)(table name)(\.a dot or not)(column name)(any string) ] (repeat N times)
```

**EDIT**

1. I am writing in C#
2. The pattern should be a bit more general that:
   \b(tc(?:mcs|com)\d{3}XXX.\w+)\b

in the sense that table name is 5 characters (the first is always a `t`, followed by 4 random chars) followed by 3 random digits

table column is 4 random chars

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/yP7rR0/1) and [this](https://regex101.com/r/yP7rR0/2) ?

Comment: internet a bit blocked...

Comment: @Mariano.. perfect!
please respond so I can upvote ;-)

Comment: ehm.. a couple of problems, please see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to match the whole command, I'll simply match each table or column independently. Since tables have digits in its name, there's few chances it could match something else.

1. Match column names with:

   ```
   \b(t\w{4}\d{3}\.\w{4})\b
   ```
2. Match table names with:

   ```
   \b(t\w{4}\d{3})\b
   ```

Then, we can replace each with the desired value: `"$1YYY"` and `"$1XXX"` respectively. The patterns use these constructs:

- <kbd>`\b`</kbd> Matches a word boundary (a word char on one side and not a word char on the other).
- <kbd>`\w{4}`</kbd> Matches 4 word chars (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`).
- <kbd>`\d{3}`</kbd> Matches 3 digits (`[0-9]`).

---

**Code:**

```
string input = @"SELECT tcmcs003.*, tccom130.nama, tccom705.dsca, tcmcs052.dsca, tccom100.nama  
FROM tcmcs003, tccom130,tccom705,tcmcs052,tccom100
WHERE  tcmcs003.cadr REFERS TO tccom130 
AND tcmcs003.casi REFERS TO tccom705  
AND tcmcs003.cprj REFERS TO tcmcs052 
AND tcmcs003.bpid REFERS TO tccom100
ORDER BY tcmcs003._index1";

string Pattern1 = @"\b(t\w{4}\d{3}\.\w{4})\b";
string Pattern2 = @"\b(t\w{4}\d{3})\b";
Regex r1 = new Regex(Pattern1);
Regex r2 = new Regex(Pattern2);
string replacement1 = "YYY";
string replacement2 = "XXX";

string result = "";

result = r1.Replace(input, "$1" + replacement1);
result = r2.Replace(result, "$1" + replacement2);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

<kbd>[ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/M61EBr)</kbd>

Comment: **Note:** I used `\w` for the *random chars*. It matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Feel free to change it accordingly.